# addOnPageChangeListener is undefined

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I have downloaded a code from Github.I can not run the program.The problem is the method **addOnPageChangeListener** is undefined.Here's the error:

> The method addOnPageChangeListener(TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener) is undefined for the type ViewPager

What should i do? Should I use another method? Here's the code:

```
import android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class FourthActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

// Need this to link with the Snackbar
private CoordinatorLayout mCoordinator;
//Need this to set the title of the app bar
private CollapsingToolbarLayout mCollapsingToolbarLayout;
private FloatingActionButton mFab;
private Toolbar mToolbar;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private ViewPager mPager;
private YourPagerAdapter mAdapter;
private TabLayout mTabLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fourth);
    mCoordinator = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.root_coordinator);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, mToolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close);
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();

    mTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    mAdapter = new YourPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    //Notice how the Tab Layout links with the Pager Adapter
    mTabLayout.setTabsFromPagerAdapter(mAdapter);

    //Notice how The Tab Layout adn View Pager object are linked
    mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mPager);
    mPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(mTabLayout));


    mFab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Notice how the Coordinator Layout object is used here
            Snackbar.make(mCoordinator, "FAB Clicked", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).setAction("DISMISS", null).show();
        }
    });

    //Notice how the title is set on the Collapsing Toolbar Layout instead of the Toolbar
    mCollapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.title_activity_fourth));
}
```

Comment: `addOnPageChangeListener ` takes `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener` as parameter instead of `TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener` . so git repo link from which u have downloaded project.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK The error is not because of the parameter.The problem is there is no method addOnPageChangeListener  for mPager which is an object of ViewPager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find your dependency of android support-v4 library in build.gradle,  upgrade the version to 22.2.1 or 23.0.1, the line looks like this

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
```

Comment: how you import your support library?

Comment: just find the new version of support library and replace the old one

Comment: Hi Derek Fung, I don't understand your answer. In fact there is no such thing as compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1' in the android manifest file. It is an XML file. You cannot have that kind of line floating anywhere on it. I think you are referring to the Android targetSDK version? Am I correct?

Comment: Thanks for correcting. I have fixed that, it should be the build.gradle file.