# Want to start animation on viewpager page but pages are preloading

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

In my projects I have several screen(Fragments) and I want to give animation to the fragments elements(views). I have used view pager and viewpager adapter and fragments. The main problems I am facing-

1. On starting of is loading 2 pages like on start it is loading page1 and page 2. If swiping to second page then it is loading 3rd page automatically.
2. I need to show the animation for the view(RelativeLayout) which is using [Universal tween engine](http://www.aurelienribon.com/blog/projects/universal-tween-engine/).

Is there something wrong with the code?

Here is the **MainActivity.java** code-

```
    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {    
    ViewPager viewPager;
    PagerAdapter adapter;
    CirclePageIndicator mIndicator;
    private int mWidthScreen;
    private int mHeightScreen;
    private Bundle bundle;
    private List<Fragment> frgScreens;
    private int selectedtheme;
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.viewpager_main); // Get the view from viewpager_main.xml        
        buildargument();        
        initialisePaging(); // Page creating function       
    }

    private void initialisePaging(int theme) {
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);       
        frgScreens = new Vector<Fragment>(); // clearing old entries        
        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

                //Loading fragment # position

                //Instead of starting animation from onCreate start it from here 
                //Only for the first time (for page 1) this callback will not trigger
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            }
        });

        frgScreens = this.basicThemes();
        // Bind result to ViewPagerAdapter
        adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this.getSupportFragmentManager(), frgScreens);
        this.viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    /*
     * Basic fragments
     */
    private List<Fragment> basicThemes() {
        // declaring fragments Group Basic
        Fragment frgBasic1 = Fragment.instantiate(this, Basic1.class.getName());
        Fragment frgBasic2 = Fragment.instantiate(this, Basic2.class.getName());
        Fragment frgBasic3 = Fragment.instantiate(this, Basic3.class.getName());
        Fragment frgBasic4 = Fragment.instantiate(this, Basic4.class.getName()); 
        Fragment frgBasic5 = Fragment.instantiate(this, Basic5.class.getName()); 

        // Passing arguments
        frgBasic1.setArguments(bundle);
        frgBasic2.setArguments(bundle);
        frgBasic3.setArguments(bundle);
        frgBasic4.setArguments(bundle); 
        frgBasic5.setArguments(bundle);



        // Loading screens into Fragment list
        List<Fragment> frgBasicScreens = new Vector<Fragment>();

        frgBasicScreens.add(frgBasic1);
        frgBasicScreens.add(frgBasic2);
        frgBasicScreens.add(frgBasic3);
        frgBasicScreens.add(frgBasic4); 
        frgBasicScreens.add(frgBasic5);

    return frgBasicScreens;

}

private void getScreenHeightWidhth() {
    DisplayMetrics localDisplayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(localDisplayMetrics);
    this.mWidthScreen = localDisplayMetrics.widthPixels;
    this.mHeightScreen = localDisplayMetrics.heightPixels;
    mHandler.post(
            new DisplayToast(this, "Width Screen:" + mWidthScreen + ". Height Screen: " + mHeightScreen + "."));
}

private void buildargument() {
    this.bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("mWidthScreen", this.mWidthScreen);
}   

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}}
```

Now **ViewPagerAdapter.java**

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {    
private List<Fragment> screens; 

public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments ) {
    super(fm);      
    this.screens = fragments;       
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
    // getting the position of the item
    return this.screens.get(pos);       
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // Getting the size of screen passed
    return this.screens.size();
}}
```

**skinbase.java** is the common class used by all the basics screen some shared methods.

```
public abstract class SkinsBase extends Fragment
{
 protected int mWidthScreen;
 protected int mHeightScreen;
 public int skinHeight;
 public int skinWidth;
 public final int textShadowSize = 2;
 .................
 }
```

now **basic1.java**

```
public class Basic1 extends SkinsBase { 
private RelativeLayout mBlueBackground;
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private static final String TAG = "Basic1";

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (container == null) {
        return null;
    }       
    mContext = container.getContext();
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.blank_viewpager_item, container, false);
    mLayoutForeground = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.relative);

    mBlueBackground = initshape(getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent_blue_80),this.mWidthScreen, (int) (0.10F * this.mWidthScreen), 0,(int) (0.12F *this.mWidthScreen));     
    this.mLayoutForeground.addView(this.mBlueBackground);   

    Log.e(TAG, "Inside basic 1 ");
    return v;
}



public RelativeLayout initshape(int intColor,int intWidthscreen, int intHeight, int intMerginLeft,int intMerginTop) {
    RelativeLayout localRelativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this.mContext);             
    localRelativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(intColor);       
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams localLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(intWidthscreen, intHeight);
    localLayoutParams.setMargins(intMerginLeft, intMerginTop, 0, 0);
    localRelativeLayout.setLayoutParams(localLayoutParams);         
    return localRelativeLayout;
}   

public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}}
```

Same way other **basic2.java, basic3.java, basic4.java.....** are like **basic1.java**

I need to apply animation to **RelativeLayout**. Is it possible? And I want the start of the animation when the page loads not before that.

Answer (score 3):

It is the default behavior of view-pager that it preload at-least 1 page from both side of current page. See following links

[ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0) doesn't work as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073214/viewpager-setoffscreenpagelimit0-doesnt-work-as-expected)

So what you can do is Instead of starting animation onCreate start it from `onPageScrolled` callback

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        //Loading fragment # position

        //Instead of starting animation from onCreate start it from here 
        //Only for the first time (for page 1) this callback will not trigger
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    }
});
```

See [setOffscreenPageLimit](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int))

> Set the number of pages that should be retained to either side of the
>   current page in the view hierarchy in an idle state. Pages beyond this
>   limit will be recreated from the adapter when needed.
>
> This is offered as an optimization. If you know in advance the number
>   of pages you will need to support or have lazy-loading mechanisms in
>   place on your pages, tweaking this setting can have benefits in
>   perceived smoothness of paging animations and interaction. If you have
>   a small number of pages (3-4) that you can keep active all at once,
>   less time will be spent in layout for newly created view subtrees as
>   the user pages back and forth.
>
> You should keep this limit low, especially if your pages have complex
>   layouts. **This setting defaults to 1.**

Comment: Thanks @penguin for you help. When I am adding it to code getting error-**The method addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener(){}) is undefined for the type ViewPager** . I am trying this inside of  **initialisePaging()** method.

Comment: Can you please help me here

Comment: update android support-v4 library in build.gradle, current version is 23.2.0 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32396846/addonpagechangelistener-is-undefined

Comment: Sorry current version is 23.2.1 http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/

Comment: I have updated the latest version to Android 23. Still the error did not go. Just wondering If I have added the code correct position. Please check the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

Overriding `setUserVisibleHint()` in each of my pages/fragments worked for me. You can simply call `view.startAnimation(animation)` inside your `setUserVisibleHint()`. However, there is one problem with this approach:

> In fragments, `setUserVisibleHint()` gets called before
>   `onCreateView()` and `onViewCreated`.

The implication of this is that when the fragment starts for the first time and you call `view.startAnimation(animation)` inside `setUserVisibleHint()`, view and animation would both be null and the app would crash.

**How then can you fix this problem?**

In each of your pages/fragments, simply declare a global boolean (let's call it fresh_load), use this boolean to check whether the fragment is being loaded for the first time. Here's an illustration:

```
boolean fresh_load = true;
Animation move;
ImageView car;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_carousel_two, container, false);

    // init move and car variables

    if(fresh_load) {
        car.startAnimation(animation);
        fresh_load = false;
    }

    return view;
}

@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);

    if((isVisible() && animation != null) && !fresh_load) {
        car.startAnimation(move);
    }
}
```

I hope this helps. Merry coding!