# Stop preloading pages in viewpager example

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-pageradapter

I am looking for and example source code for stop pre-loading pages in viewpager. Normally android viewpager loads the next and previous page(s) automatically. My target is to use viewpager and I want to show animation on views(which are present in the pages) when it visible to the user. Basically it is to continue with the previous of  [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35956867/want-to-start-animation-on-viewpager-page-but-pages-are-preloading).

If you can give me any working example(complete code) it will be so kind. I found so many but did not find any working implementation.
Thanks for your help.
Regards
Biswajit

Comment: look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024739/how-to-determine-when-fragment-becomes-visible-in-viewpager?rq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like you already know there is no way of stopping viewpagers from loading . The only way out is to use this method setUserVisibleHint add this to your fragment, and do all the animation you want to in this method

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser) {
        // animate here
     Log.e(TAG, "animate here");
    }else{
     Log.e(TAG, "fragment is no longer visible");
       // fragment is no longer visible
    }
}
```

This will be called only when that particular tab is visible to user.

Comment: Well perfect. it is loading with pause.

Comment: If this did solve your problem ,please accept the answer.

Comment: Well it solved more than partially. but while loading it is showing "Animate here" and when it is no longer visible. Then **first it is showing "Animate here" and the showing "fragment is no longer visible"**. I have edited your code. Please look for your reference.

Comment: I have never come across this problem. Will have to look into. But It is maybe because when you change between tab , at a point, there is some portion of two adjacent tabs that is visible, so maybe thats why.

Comment: Sure. Thanks. will be waiting for your answers.