# ImageView not updating in viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a viewpager with 5-6 fragments in it. Each fragment is of the same class and contains an imageView. I am trying to show an animation drawable in the imageView. The imageView is being shown empty in first two fragments initially (as only those are cached by pager) once i scroll to 4 fragment and scroll back all fragments show the images being animated.

```
imgView.setBackgroundDrawable(animationDrawable);
        imgView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                animationDrawable.start();
            }
        });
```

Comment: and where are you calling this code?

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36369413/stop-preloading-pages-in-viewpager-example

Comment: @DrilonBlakqori the code is called in onCreateView

Comment: @Anil Did try that didn't work

Comment: @pvn I think we can't stop preloading functionality of view pager,so we have to check which [fragment is visible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024739/how-to-determine-when-fragment-becomes-visible-in-viewpager/12523627#12523627) on the screen