# determine touch on a view inside viewpager page

Tags: android, view, touch, motionevent, motion-detection

I have some pages which is loading into viewpager. I want to determine if there any way to find out if user touch the view(inside page) when the page is visible?  My view pager page view is something like this [Basic1.java and initshape() method as describe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35956867/want-to-start-animation-on-viewpager-page-but-pages-are-preloading). 
Please let me know any more information is required.

Answer (score 0):

implement following code in a page(fragment) you want to detect touch event.

```
@Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Inflate the layout containing a title and body text.
ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater
                .inflate(R.layout.fragment_slide, container, false);
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.layout)// get your root  layout
layout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            Log.v(null, "TOUCH EVENT"); // handle your fragment touch  here
            return false;
        }
    });
      return rootView;
    }
```

Comment: will try and let you know the result.